# Could a Borg member survive a ‘Star Trek: The Motion Picture’-type transporter malfunction?

Tags: star-trek, borg

Given how durable and adaptable the Borg are, could they survive the type of transporter malfunction seen in ‘Star Trek:The Motion Picture’(1979)? If so, could this Borg member reshape itself into humanoid form?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you're going to find a definitive answer to this. Note that we don't actually see the result of the transporter malfunction:

[image: Star Trek transporter malfunction scene]

We just hear a vague description:

> What we got back didn't live long. Fortunately.

So the answer to whether a Borg drone could "reshape" itself depends on the exact nature of the malfunction, which we don't know. Like [Revenant](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/105500/revenant) said in their answer, I would guess that a Borg drone (or a member of any species) could survive a minor malfunction, but not one that caused irreparable damage.

Your question is a bit like asking: could a Borg drone survive a car crash? The answer of course depends on the exact nature of the accident, and there isn't anything special about the Borg in this regard.

Another thing to consider is that the Borg don't value the life of a single drone. From [cbr.com](https://www.cbr.com/borg-facts-only-true-star-trek-fans-know/), emphasis mine:

> [image: Borg children]
>
> The Borg operate in such a way as to strive for perfection, which means they don't have much of a tolerance for defective parts. Parts, in this instance refers to Drones. **When one Drone becomes damaged, it may be simpler to salvage the parts from it than to attempt reviving it and returning it to the collective. This has been demonstrated in a number of episodes of Star Trek: Voyager when Seven's parents were on a ship observing some Drones. They noted that a damaged Drone was scrapped for parts rather than repaired or healed in any way.** When a Drone is infected or altered in some way by an outside force, they are removed from the collective and left to fend for themselves. This happened to a number of children (pictured) who made their way onto Voyager after being severed from the Borg whole.

So even if a drone could survive a transporter malfunction, the Borg might scrap it for parts anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes a Borg drone could most likely survive a minor malfunction (a Borg drone was actually created by a transporter malfunction at one point).  However, this does not make the Borg special, a member of almost any species could probably survive a minor malfunction, depending on how one defines minor malfunction.

If the Borg gets liquefied how you define survive matters, the knowledge even the personality of the drone exists within the collective so while a physical body dies the personality can be copied onto a different drone at any time.

Comment: Isn't the whole idea of the hive mind that no single one drone has a unique personality? The only times I've seen personality have been in rogue drones that are disconnected from the hive, of not able mention, 7 of 9.

Comment: When was a Borg drone created by a transporter malfunction?

Comment: When I say “transporter malfunction”, I’m talking about the kind that causes irreversible damage to the matter of the living thing that’s being transported.

Comment: @Wikis Voyager S5E2 Drone nanoprobes from Seven combined with the mobile emitter during a transport leading to an advanced drone being created.

Comment: @Gnemlock S5E7 infinite regress shows Seven being affected by a malfunctioning piece of Borg technology which causes several personalities to emerge, which I always took to mean that while an individual drone has no personality the neural patterns of the individual it once was is stored somewhere in the collective.